# Custom function with MySQLi extension issue

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I really don't know what should be wrong with query written below this

`$username` is passed by form with POST method, $mysqli is connection variable, code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "securelogin");

function usernameCheck($username, $mysqli) {
        $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt > 1) {
            $stmt->close();
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

This function checks if username already exists in database

~~~~

I have solved this function with following code

```
function usernameCheck($username, $mysqli) {
    $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows != 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

But this is, like you said, SQL Injection vulnerable. I just don't get it how to code that into non-injectable

Comment: Put the $mysqli inside the function with the keyword global.`global $mysqli;`

Comment: What is the problem? On what line the problem begins? Echo every line of your code and see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is vulnerable to sql injection. Please use prepare statement correctly.

```
$query = 'select username from user where username = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute() or die('error: ' . $mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_result($username);
return $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

With mysqli prepared statements.

```
 function usernameCheck($username, $mysqli) {

     $query = "select username from user where username =?";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
     $stmt->execute() or die('error: ' . $mysqli->error);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;  
     $stmt->bind_result($username);
     $stmt->fetch();

     if ($num_of_rows == 0) {
        return false;
     }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! :) But $stmt always gives me public 'num_rows => null'

Comment: this is how far I got.
`function usernameCheck($username, $mysqli) {
$query = 'SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = "$username"';
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
return FALSE;
}
return FALSE;
}
return FALSE;
}
return FALSE;
}`

Function works good. But it gives an error -> Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement. I assume that query is bad but I don't see anything wrong with it!

Comment: @bubalowski. You have the if condition such that if there is a matching row exists you are returning false. And if there is one row you are returning true. Check you want it like or the just opposite..

Comment: Thanks for edit! Now it gives zero errors, but it seems like your updated version doesn't check if username already exists in database. I tested it few times but just passes any typed username.
By the way, I'm checking functions with the following code: `usernameCheck($username, $mysqli) === FALSE`
Is this the "correct" way?

Comment: yes its like that. You have to check the logic while return true or false conditions please

Comment: I have updated code that, if there is no matching records found, it returns false. And if a match found then returns true.

Comment: It just doesn't work for me. It always gives me "username already exists" error code for any username typed. Seems I will have to dig deeper into these MySQLi functions and watch/read some tutorials.

Comment: can you echo the $num_of_rows variable inside the function, before calling if loop

Comment: $num_of_rows is (always) 0 and it gives another error "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement". This error appears if I try to echo that variable